# How to specify the business type of a LocalBusiness? (SDTT doesn't recognize a "Gardening" type)

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets-tool

Implementing Schema.org [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) in JSON-LD. The business is for a Gardening.

How can I specify the TYPE to Gardening if it is not recognized in Google’s SDTT?

[image]

So I use this:

[image]

So where in `LocalBusiness` do you define the business TYPE?

Comment: The fact that you attached the tag 'seo' to this question makes me believe that you believe that Schema will improve your SEO, which is a wrong assumption. Google and Bing do not reward for Schema nor does it directly improve rankings.

Comment: @SimonHayter "Does Schema Improve Your Search Rankings?
There is no evidence that microdata has a direct affect on organic search rankings. Nonetheless, rich snippets do make your webpages appear more prominently in SERPs. This improved visibility has been shown to improve click-through rates." Source: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/schema-101-improve-seo-results/204858/   - And Rand Fishkin of Moz has performed experiments showing that click through rates does boost SERP position. So this question is very much SEO related

Comment: @michaeld... `Schema nor does it directly improve rankings`... you just pointed out exactly what I said... Schema does not directly improve your rankings... Rich snippets increase indirectly and LocalBusiness, as asked in this question, has zero Rich Snippets... therefore the tag SEO as I previously mentioned does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of `sameAs`: something like this way:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Service",
  "serviceType": "Gardening",
  "sameAs": "http://dbpedia.org/page/Gardening",
  "provider": {
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "name": "ACME Gardening Services"
  },
  "areaServed": {
    "@type": "State",
    "name": "Massachusetts"
  },
"hasOfferCatalog": {
    "@type": "OfferCatalog",
    "name": "Gardening services",
    "sameAs": "http://dbpedia.org/page/Gardening",
    "itemListElement": [
 {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
              "@type": "Service",
              "name": "Garden Planting",
              "sameAs": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Garden_planting"

         } },
          {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "itemOffered": {
              "@type": "Service",
              "name": "Garden maintanance",
              "sameAs": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Garden_maintenance"
            }
            }
]
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Any other option?  Already have URLs  for SameAs

Comment: No. There is no such defined service type, but Schema.org allows to be extended in any way. if you already have this property in your code, you should post full code example.

Comment: I’m not sure if it makes sense to specify this `sameAs` for the `Service`. It conveys that DBpedia’s "Gardening" *is* the same entity as OP’s service, which is not true. -- And when using DBpedia URIs to describe the thing (instead of the page), [`/resource/` (instead of `/page/`) should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44073920/1591669).

Comment: @unor do you really mean, Google will fail on understanding it?

Comment: @Evgeniy: No idea, can only speculate (for rich results, Google would likely ignore all properties unless they are recommended/required according to their own documentation). But Google is not the only consumer of the data. -- And if it would get common that properties aren’t used for their intended purpose, they could lose their meaning and consumers might stop making use of them.